# Code Reference for Django in PyCharm Professional not working

Tags: python, django, pycharm

In a `urls.py` file like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

Or, `views.py` like this:

```
    template_name = 'myapp/index.html'
```

When I press `Ctrl` key and hover over `'myapp.url'` or `'myapp/index.html'`, I should be able to go to these files after clicking on these both strings. This is also known as "Code Referencing" as most of the people know. But, in my PyCharm Professional Edition, I am not able to do so. I cannot do as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html).

Comment: Did you enable this as a Django project? PyCharm has support for Django.

Comment: I found that you are right. I actually didn't enable it as Django project. Thanks, @WillemVanOnsem